# Python detecting a literal backslash as a line continuation character

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I stop python seeing "\\" as an invalid line continuation character and start seeing it as a literal backslash? This is a chronic problem but as an example this line of code to move files in a folder to another subfolder :

```
[rename(I, f"Mainfolder\\InvalidFileStorage\\{ I.rsplit("\\").pop() }") for I in InvalidFiles]
```

(ps, I am aware that this list comprehension might not be right yet, but I haven't been able to bug test it since I can't run the code without it complaining about line continuation characters)
I am aware from previous instances of this happening that you can typically solve the problem by just moving the code into several lines and using variables to store it, but that would take this simple one liner and make it several times larger and I hate having to constantly do that for otherwise simple code segments.

Comment: Backslashes are forbidden between the braces in an f-string.

Comment: I would avoid an f-string altogether here; use something like `Path("Mainfolder/InvalidFileStorage") / I.rsplit("\\").pop()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue comes from the fact that python's f-string parsing is quite weak and can't handle quotes inside expression areas, as they'll break the string:

```py
f"asdf {"a" + "b"} asdf" # not allowed
```

However, quotes of the opposite type are:

```py
f"asdf {'a' + 'b'} asdf" # fine
```

Once you fix this issue, it'll error saying that backslashes aren't allowed inside an f-string expression. The easiest way to circumvent this is to just move it to a function:

```py
def process(s):
    return s.rsplit("\\").pop()

[rename(I, f"Mainfolder\\InvalidFileStorage\\{ process(I) }") for I in InvalidFiles]
```

Comment: Another approach: Don't use literal backslash: `[rename(I, f"Mainfolder\\InvalidFileStorage\\{ I.rsplit(chr(0x5c)).pop() }") for I in InvalidFiles]`. Still ugly (magic numbers are the devil, and calling `chr` over and over is wasteful), but keeps it a one-liner. Or just give up on f-strings: `[rename(I, "Mainfolder\\InvalidFileStorage\\{}".format(I.rsplit("\\")[-1])) for I in InvalidFiles]`